# Filtering every positive value for every negative in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a dataset with financial data. Sometimes, a product gets refunded, resulting in a negative count of the product (so the money gets returned). I want to conditionally filter these rows out of the dataset.
Example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)

df <- tibble(
  count = sample(c(-1,1),80,replace = TRUE,prob=c(.2,.8)),
  id = rep(1:4,20)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(count))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id total
  <int> <dbl>
1     1    10
2     2    14
3     3    16
4     4    10
```

id = 1 has 15 positive counts and 5 negatives. `(15 - 5= 10)`. I want to keep 10 values in df with id = 1 with the positive values.
id = 2 has 17 positive counts and 3 negatives. `(17- 3 = 14)`. I want to keep 14 values in df  with id = 2 with the positive values.

In the end, this condition should be True `nrow(df) == sum(df$count)`

Unfortunately, a filtering join such as `anti_join()` will remove all the rows. For some reason I cannot think of another option to filter the tibble.

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "uncount" using the `total` column to get the number of repeats of each row.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(count)) %>%
  uncount(total) %>%
  mutate(count = 1)
#> # A tibble: 50 x 2
#>       id count
#>    <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1
#>  2     1     1
#>  3     1     1
#>  4     1     1
#>  5     1     1
#>  6     1     1
#>  7     1     1
#>  8     1     1
#>  9     1     1
#> 10     1     1
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This seems to be the answer! Thank you!